how to change permission for symbolic link target directory
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {}\; if I give this it changes the every dir but it not changing the /var/www/html/storage.
so while checking why the storage folder is not changing at that point i found that /var/www/html/public/ $ storage-> /var/www/html/storage/app/public.
how i can change the permission 755 for all the dir inside the /var/www/html?

Hi thanks for the responses, Using script when we run the "sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {};" its changing the all sub dir in /var/www/html. but only /var/www/html/storage is not changing . so while checking the /var/www/html/public$ storage -> /var/www/html/storage/app/public for your refer i have attached image
enter image description here
so when we run the script it should change all dir and sub dir with in /var/www/html

Your paths are confusing. The first one you list is /var/www/html/storage. There is no public here. The you talk about /var/www/html/public/storage with a public in it being a symlink to /var/www/html/storage/app/public. Which one is the one with permissions not changing?

Hi thanks for the responses,

storage is a symlink, not a directory. Symlinks have alway 777 permissions. Why do you expect a symlinks mode to be changed when you use find to change the mode of directories?

if you want the change to also follow symlinks use -L but symlinks themself are ALWAYS 777
